# I am not able to access any wireless network

Tags: wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and I just put 13.10 on my computer. I not able to see any possible wireless connection. Usually, or at least with windows vista I am able to view wireless connections that my computer could connect to, but it only gives me wired connections. I already installed the Braodcom driver. Also sometimes the Ethernet stops working as well randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on terminal,

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

And then search for wifi networks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with ubuntu 11.10, 12.10.
BUT when I was trying to install ubuntu 13.10 , I checked the option of 
" Install this third party software "
and it worked for me !!

See step 2 in this link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest